# PasswordSignInAsync - Failing when calling this programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, forms-authentication

Please help, I want to test a service method - and during this testing I want to forcefully log-in a user by providing the user name and password - this will not be used for production, simply for a test I am conducting. But when I get the sign in manager and call the PasswordSignInAsync I receive a strange error, this error is not generated when going via Login.cshtml.cs code which reads the same?

[image]

Comment: Hi I am trying to test an application locally being run in Visual Studio Code. I am using POSTMAN to call some Api's. I do not know how to sign in or bypass the Authorization 'roles' without commenting out all the Authorize tags. Do you have any advise that is better than trying to force a logon?

Comment: Thats a classical [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/392095). You have A problem A and you think you can solve it with B and you ask how to do it with B rather than asking help with the original problem. Better rephrase your question to name your actual problem (maybe with some code if required, not screenshoted code), so people may give you proper answer to the real problem you are having with

Comment: Thank you for that kind advice.

Comment: I have done just that and posted a new question like this "How to bypass [Authorize(Roles = “Admin”)] tag from all service calls when doing integration testing?"